# Linked list in hash tables

Tags: java, linked-list, hashtable

Suppose we wish to repeatedly search a linked list of length N elements, each of which contains a very long string key. How might we take advantage of the hash value when searching the list for an element with a given key?

Comment: Is this a Java specific question, or is it asking for an algorithm in general for this.

Comment: Are you able to move the keys to another data structure or do you have to use the linked list?

Answer (score 0):

Insert the keys into a hash table. Then you can search in (theoretically) constant time.

Comment: Hash tables in java provide constant time add/remove on average (i.e. theta(1)), not in theory.  In theory, they provide O(n) time for add/remove.

Comment: There are many hash table implementations. Are you referring to the HashTable class? I was talking about hashes in general.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the hashes prepared before searching the list and you need to be able to access hash of a string in constant time. Then you can first compare the hashes and only compare strings when hashes match. You can use a hashtable instead of a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

The hash value of a String (`hashCode`) is a bit like an id for the string.  Not completely unique, but usually pretty unique.  You can a `HashMap` to store the String keys and their values.  `HashMap`, as its name suggests, uses the Strings' hash values to efficiently store and retrieve values.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what constraints you're working under here (i.e. this might take way too much memory depending on how big the strings are), but if you have to maintain the linked list you could create a HashMap that maps the strings to their position in the list which would allow you to retrieve any string from the list with 2 constant time operations.

Comment: Even if you have the position of a string inside a linked list, you still have to traverse the entire list to retrieve it. It has no random access.

Comment: Ah yes - excellent point. Usually I try to actually think before posting, but obviously I failed this time - thanks for correcting my error!

Answer (score 0):

Put it in HashSet. The search algorithms will use the hash for each String value inserted.